# How does sharpening a pencil make it darker?

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

Why does a sharp pencil write better than a blunt one? [image]

Note that the force applied on each case is identical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you make a line on a piece of paper using a pencil, you are shearing (sliding) off layers of graphite from the pencil 'lead' and depositing them on the paper. The sharper the pencil point, the smaller the area over which the frictional force between pencil 'lead' and the paper is concentrated. So the shearing stress on the 'lead' is greater, and graphite layers slide off more copiously as you move the pencil across the paper.

Comment: Might it be that for a sharper pencil the (same amount of) graphite is spread over a smaller area and therefore the line appears to be darker?

Comment: Or more graphite $and$ spread over a smaller area?